# How do i turn a label invisible/visible when I click a button in a WPF .NET Framework Application in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, .net-framework-version

How would i make a button invisible when I press a button in a WPF .NET Framework application in Visual Studio c#.

Comment: If you provide a sample of the code you are using or what you have tried already it will help others provide better information.

Answer (score 1):

Simple example using [`BooleanToVisibilityConverter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.booleantovisibilityconverter?view=netframework-4.8):

```
<Window>
  <Window.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter" />
  </Window.Resources>

  <StackPanel>
    <ToggleButton x:Name="ToggleButton" />
    <Label Visibility="{Binding ElementName=ToggleButton, Property=IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}" />
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

Click the button to switch between hidden and visible

```
private void Btn1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Visibility=label1.Visibility == Visibility.Hidden ? Visibility.Visible :  Visibility.Hidden;
        }
```